# Extract specific string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to extract specific characters from string. I have tried using Split and replace to get data. But any other alternative is there to extract?
**Following is input string**

```
  Input1-    
    q={!tag=tagForType}(Type:(ABC))

  Input2-  
    q={!tag=tagForType}(Type:(ABC OR XYZ))
```

**Output required in list format.**

```
  Output1-  List1{ABC}
  Output2- List1{ABC ,XYZ)
```

**Following is code I have tried to extract such data**

```
 if (s.contains("Type")) {                               
    List = s.split("Type:\\(");
    String s1 = List[1].replaceAll("\\W", "");
    List1 = s1.split("OR");                                
 }
```

Any other alternative?

Comment: This doesn't look like JavaScript. You cannot declare a variable with `String` type.

Comment: Shouldn't it be tagged `java`?

Comment: Sorry it was java.. Thanks for informing

Comment: Why do you want the alternative method ? Do you face any performance issue

Comment: Instead of split and relaceAll method.. is there any better alternative to extract data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this solution with regexes.

```
    String input = "q={!tag=tagForType}(Type:(ABC OR XyZ OR ORT))(Type:(ABC))";
    Pattern findType = Pattern.compile("Type:(\\([ \\w]+\\))");
    Pattern extractLists = Pattern.compile("(\\(| OR )([\\w]+)");
    Matcher typeMatcher = findType.matcher(input);
    while (typeMatcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(typeMatcher.group(1));

        Matcher listMatcher = extractLists.matcher(typeMatcher.group(1));
        while (listMatcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(listMatcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

This prints the following:

```
(ABC OR XYZ OR ORT)
ABC
XyZ
ORT
(ABC)
ABC
```

Of course you might need to do something else with the groups, I currently am just printing them out.

Note that here I demonstrate how this solution works with multiple `Type:` in the same string, which I think your solution will not handle.

Also currently I am assuming the amount of intervals in between the parts is fixed, but this can also be worked on if using regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 String EXAMPLE_TEST = "q={!tag=tagForType}(Type:(ABC))";

 pattern = "^.*?Type:.*?([\\w\\s]+).*";

 String updated = EXAMPLE_TEST.replaceAll(pattern, "$1"  ); 

 System.out.println(updated);
```

For splitting with OR

```
String[] split = updated.split(" OR ");
for(int i=0;i<split.length;i++) 
 System.out.println(split[i]);
```

Comment: This will not handle the ` OR ` splitting I think.